# AWS Web Identity Federation Playground fails with "No AWSAccess Key was presented"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am on the AWS Web Identity Federation Playground (https://web-identity-federation-playground.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html)

I successfully got the temporary-credentials , however all calls to S3 (ListObject, GetObject) fail with the error code : **`AccessDenied`
  No AWSAccessKey was presented.**

I tried doing this in my own JS code (for the PutObject Call) and that also fails with the same error code.

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

**It worked fine for me!**

Here are the steps I followed:

- Went to [Web Identity Federation Playground](https://web-identity-federation-playground.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html)
- Selected **Google** tab
- Clicked "Google sign in"
- Authenticated to Google and clicked **Allow**
- Clicked **Proceed to Step 2**
- Clicked **Call AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity**
- Clicked **Proceed to Step 3**
- Clicked **Go**

I'm using Chrome on a Mac.